# Cant call and validate a formset in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a fromset that I am working with in a django view and I can not seem to figure out how to call the formset to validate it and grab the values from the forms. Is there a way for me to call the formset after the user submits it and then validate all of the fields before I start gathering the users inputs into the forms... Here is the code that I have: also is there a way to create a prefix for each of the forms within the formset that are unique so that when i am grabbing the values I can do it much easier than the default id or lables for the fields.

The validation code would be in line 26 & 27.

```
def addTransaction(request, groupId, recordId):
    if 'username' not in request.session:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        username = request.session['username']
        currentUser = User.objects.get(username = username)
        group = Group.objects.get(id=groupId)
        record = Record.objects.get(id=recordId)
        transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(record=recordId).all().count()
        SplitFormSet = formset_factory(IndividualSplitTransactionForm, extra=transactions)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if record.split == 1:
                form = EvenSplitTransactionForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    cd = form.cleaned_data
                    amount = cd['amount']
                    description = cd['description']
                    split_amount = SplitEven(record, amount)
                    for trans in transactions:
                        if trans.record.id == record.id:
                            trans.description = description
                            trans.amount = split_amount
                            trans.save()
                    return redirect('group_home', groupId=group.id)
            if record.split == 2:
                formset = SplitFormSet(request.POST)
                if formset.is_valid():
                    cheese = 'cheese'
                    print(cheese)
                # this is where i want to iterate though the formset and get the info
                # that i need from the forms that the user submitted.
                # form = formList(request.POST)
                # if form.is_valid():
                #     cd = form.cleaned_data
                #     for transaction in transactions:
                #         amount = transaction.user.username + '-amount'
                #         description = transaction.user.username + '-description'
                #         currentAmount = cd[amount]
                #         currentDescription = cd[description]
                #         transaction.amount = currentAmount
                #         transaction.description = currentDescription
                #         transaction.save()
                #     return redirect('group_home', groupId=group.id)
            return redirect('accounts')
        else:
            if record.split == 1:
                form = EvenSplitTransactionForm()
                message = 'fill out the form below'
                parameters = {
                    'record':record,
                    'form':form,
                    'message':message,
                    'transactions':transactions,
                }
                return render(request, 'tabs/add_even_transactions.html', parameters)
            if record.split == 2:
                print(SplitFormSet)
                message = 'message'
                parameters = {
                    'record':record,
                    'SplitFormSet':SplitFormSet,
                    'message':message,
                    'transactions':transactions,
                }
                return render(request, 'tabs/add_individual_transaction.html', parameters)
```

**UPDATED**

I updated some of the code to include the suggested fix:

```
            if record.split == 2:
                formset = SplitFormSet(request.POST)
                for form in formset:
                    if form.is_valid():
                        cheese = 'cheese'
                        print(cheese)
```

and i am getting the following error...

```
ValidationError at /38/69/add_transaction/
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
------
for form in formset:
```

**HTML File:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Add members to {{record.name}}</h1>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in SplitFormSet %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't see you instantiating the formset with any data. Like `formset = SplitFormSet(request.POST)`

Comment: Unless that's what you're saying...You want to validate the formset before it has any data? No, you can't do that. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I want to validate it after there is data. I am going to add the request.post into the formset and see if that works @CoryMadden

Comment: so i added the request.post to the formset call and i am geting an error. if you can look at the updated part of my post...@CoryMadden

Comment: Are you including the management form in the template? See the form example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template

Comment: yes i have the management_form. I will have the html template in teh updated section @CoryMadden

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to take my dog to the park. `{% for form in SplitFormSet %}`. When does SplitFormSet get added to the view context?

Comment: in line 10. I assign SplitFormSetf and at the end is where I push the SplitFormSet in teh last set of parameters at the end... @CoryMadden

Comment: I still don't actually see that. I can't see your line numbers, either.

Comment: I changed the name of the variable i updated the code that i have sorry... @CoryMadden

Comment: OK, but your template isn't using `SplitFormSet.management_form`. And I think you need to instantiate it in the context like `{'SplitFormSet': SplitFormSet()}`

Comment: It is working now and i can iterate through the formset and get the content. One more question, can i set a prefix or label or id to each of the forms when it is created so that when i call the form in the processing it is easier to manage.. @CoryMadden I want to go through each of the forms and at the same time go through a queryset of users and attach the amount and description to the correct user and then save it to the database... (check post ofr new update section)

Comment: Awesome. I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but you can add a prefix per formset, if that's what you're wondering. To do that you'd just add the keyword `prefix` argument when instantiating the form(for validation, too). `SplitFormSet(prefix='my-prefix')`

Comment: What i mean is that when i creaate a formset with three forms, I want to add a prefix to each of the forms that is unique. an example would be one form with prefix josh, one form with prefix steve, and one form with prefix matt, all within the same formset... @CoryMadden

Comment: No, I don't think you can do that. The Django formset validation uses the prefix to validate it.

Comment: ok I will see if i can get it. i posted it in a seperate question so i will figure it out... thanks for the help. i got it running. @CoryMadden

Comment: can u give this post an up vote i need to get my reputation up to 15. @CoryMadden

Comment: Hey do you know if it is possible to select a specific result from a queryset like arrays.. something like an array when you want to call a specific item in the the array example: arrayName[2]. Is it possible do this with the results of a queryset @CoryMadden

Comment: It absolutely is. Good timing, I just walked into the office to turn my computer off. `User.objects.filter(is_active=True)[1]` will give you the second user that matches your filter.